# Implementing .ToViewModel() using AutoMapper

Tags: generics, automapper

I'm trying to ease the use of AutoMapper in my project, by implementing an extension method `.ToViewModel()`. Basically, it will just be a wrapper around the standard call, but I often find myself annoyed about how much I must type each time I want to map something. Compare the two:

```
var viewModel = Mapper.Map<DomainEntityType, ViewModelType>(entity);
// or...
var viewModel = entity.ToViewModel();
```

I feel number two would be sweet =) I've let all my entities extend `IEntity`, and all viewmodels (that correspond to an entity) extend `IViewModel<IEntity>`, and written the following extension method:

```
public static IViewModel<TEntity> ToViewModel<TEntity>(this TEntity entity) 
    where TEntity : IEntity
{
    return Mapper.Map<TEntity, IViewModel<TEntity>>(entity);
}
```

However, I'm unable to make this fly.

The following NUnit test makes an attempt at testing this (although I'm unsure if `Assert.AreEqual` really tests what I want - does it require reference equality? If so, how do I test "are equivalent"?). The test fails with the message

```
Expected: <Castle.Proxies.IViewModel`1Proxy>
But was:  <Castle.Proxies.IViewModel`1Proxy>
```

```
[Test]
public void DomainEntityTypeMapsViewModelType()
{
    var entity = new DomainEntityType();
    var oldskool = Mapper.Map<DomainEntityType, IViewModel<Entity>>(entity);
    var extension = inspectionObject.ToViewModel();

    Assert.AreEqual(oldskool, extension);
}
```

Except for the fact that my test might be testing the wrong thing, am I missing something fundamental about how AutoMapper works? Will AutoMapper ever be able to correctly map something to an interface? (I do have a class, `EntityViewModel`, that implements `ViewModel<Entity>`, but I haven't told AutoMapper specifically about it...)

Comment: Could you try to change generic type parameter constraint to where _TEntity : Entity_? Btw, are you tried to see in debugger whether two objects the same and as you are expected? Also try to change Assert.AreEqual to Assert.AreSame, it will check whether two objects references to the same object instance

Comment: i would like to know how to achieve this also...

Comment: @Baldy: I solved this - please see my answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to do this in a generic way. It required some tweaking of my objects, but here's what I did:

Since before, most of my entities inherit from `Entity<TId>` (usually `Entity<int>`, but the id could potentially be another data type, for example a GUID), which in turn implements the interface `IEntity<TId>` (with a single property `public TId ID {get;}`). The few entities that don't inherit `Entity<TId>`, at least implement `IEntity<TId>`.

I created a new class, which overrides `Equals` and `GetHashcode`:

```
public class ViewModel<TEntity, TId> : IEntity<TId>
    where TEntity : IEntity<TId>
{
    public TId ID { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var viewModel = obj as ViewModel<TEntity, TId>;
        return viewModel != null && Equals(viewModel);
    }

    public bool Equals(ViewModel<TEntity, TId> other)
    {
        return ID.Equals(other.ID);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Not only returning ID.GetHashCode() in case I want to add more
        // properties later...
        var hash = 7;
        hash = (hash * 17) + ID.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }
}
```

Now, all my viewmodels (and editmodels) inherit from this class:

```
public class EntityViewModel : ViewModel<EntityType, int>
{
    // data properties
}
```

I could then extend my entities and viewmodels with the following extension methods:

```
public static TViewModel To<TViewModel>(this IEntity entity) where TViewModel : class
{
    return Mapper.Map(entity, entity.GetType(), typeof(TViewModel)) as TViewModel;
}

public static TEntity ToEntity<TEntity, TId>(this ViewModel<TEntity, TId> viewmodel) where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>
{
    return Mapper.Map(viewmodel, viewmodel.GetType(), typeof(TEntity)) as TEntity;
}
```

A key concept to make this work was to abandon the generic overloads of `.Map`, since I didn't know the exact types I wanted to map to and from at compile time.

I can now move back and forth between the types using the following syntax:

```
var entity = new EntityType();
var viewmodel = entity.To<EntityViewModel>();

var backagain = viewmodel.ToEntity();
```

which I am quite content with, since my original goal of abstracting away AutoMapper from the implementation in the controllers have been well achieved.

You'll notice that there is a non-generic version of *IEntity* too - that's just an empty interface, which `IEntity<T>` inherits from. This might be considered dull, but there's a simple reason not to use the generic version: if you do, you'll also have to specify it as a type argument to the extension method. You'll end up with `entity.To<EntityViewModel,int>()` instead of the above syntax, since inferring type arguments is an all-or-nothing affair.